# Why is z3 failing to eliminate real quantifiers?

Tags: z3, z3py

I am attempting to eliminate quantifers from an expression s, but I have been unable to do this using z3py.

The qe tactic does not remove any quantifiers, and the qe2 tactic just hangs forever.

```
tactic = Tactic('qe')
tactic2 = Tactic('qe2')
print(s)
print(tactic(s).as_expr())
print(tactic2(s).as_expr())
```

Output

```
#s
Exists([xa0, ya0, za0, xb0, yb0, zb0],
       And((xa0 - x0)**2 + (ya0 - y0)**2 <=
           v**2*(za0 - z0)**2,
           (xb0 - x0)**2 + (yb0 - y0)**2 <=
           v**2*(zb0 - z0)**2,
           ForAll(t0,
                  Implies(And(t0 >= 0, t0 <= 1),
                          And(Or(t0*xa0 + (1 - t0)*xb0 != x0,
                                 t0*ya0 + (1 - t0)*yb0 != y0,
                                 t0*za0 + (1 - t0)*zb0 != z0),
                              And(t0*ya0 + (1 - t0)*yb0 == 0,
                                  t0*xa0 + (1 - t0)*xb0 >= 0,
                                  t0*xa0 + (1 - t0)*xb0 <= 1,
                                  t0*za0 + (1 - t0)*zb0 !=
                                  -(t0*ya0 + (1 - t0)*yb0) +
                                  -1,
                                  t0*za0 + (1 - t0)*zb0 !=
                                  -(t0*ya0 + (1 - t0)*yb0) +
                                  3,
                                  t0*za0 + (1 - t0)*zb0 !=
                                  -(t0*ya0 + (1 - t0)*yb0) +
                                  7))))))

#tactic(s).as_expr()
Exists([x!0, x!1, x!2, x!3, x!4, x!5],
       And((x!0 - x0)**2 + (x!1 - y0)**2 <=
           v**2*(x!2 - z0)**2,
           (x!3 - x0)**2 + (x!4 - y0)**2 <=
           v**2*(x!5 - z0)**2,
           Not(Exists(x!6,
                      And(And(x!6 >= 0, x!6 <= 1),
                          etc...

# tactic2(s).as_expr() just hangs
```

Is 8 quantifiers too much for z3 to handle, or am I using z3 incorrectly?

Edit: Additionally, I'm unable to check satisfiability of the expression s, it hangs forever if I run the following code

```
solver = Then('qe', 'smt').solver()
solver.add(s)
print(solver.check())
```

Comment: You haven't shown us the problem/program that generates this, so it's hard to opine. But a cursory look suggests you have a top-level `Exists`. If that's the case, it might be best not to create the exist node at all. That is, you can get rid of the quantification over `xa0, ya0, za0, xb0, yb0, zb0` by making them top-level variables. (A top-level variable in an SMT problem is already existential.) You might get better luck by formulating your problem that way. But again, stack-overflow works best if you post a minimal-viable example that can be replicated by the readers of the forum.

Comment: Also, the problem seems to be non-linear. There are no guarantees that Z3 will be able to solve such problems or that it can eliminate all quantifiers out of the box.